# AWS CLI がエンドポイントエラー

Tags: aws, aws-cli

`aws iam list-roles`

で

`Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://iam.amazonaws.com/"`

というエラーが出るんですが自分だけでしょうか

`aws s3 ls` は実行できます
権限等変更した覚えがないので一時的なDNSの不調なのでしょうか…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

昨日(2019/10/23)からAWSでDNSの障害が発生していたようです。

現在は収束していてステータス画面には表示されていません。
https://status.aws.amazon.com/
twitterや個人のブログを確認するとそれ関連のコメントや記事が流れているので確認をしてください。

また、一部ISPでもDNSの障害が起こっている情報もあります。※こちらは正式な情報は確認できていません。
その場合は、公式の情報をご確認いただき、DNSの設定を別のPublicDNSに変更するなど対応が必要になります。